# How to mount volume for docker container via yaml manifest?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I try to launch container-vm machine with following yaml:

```
version: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: simple-echo
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: ['nc', '-p', '8080', '-l', '-l', '-e', 'echo', 'hello world!']
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumeMounts:
        - name: string
          mountPath: /home
          readOnly: false
  restartPolicy: Always
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
    - name: string
      source:
        # Either emptyDir for an empty directory
        # emptyDir: {}
        # Or hostDir for a pre-existing directory on the host
        hostDir:
          path: /home
```

I expect host home directory being accessible from the container.

However, container fails to start:

```
E0619 05:02:09.477574    2212 http.go:54] Failed to read URL: invalid pod: 
[spec.volumes[0].source: invalid value '<*>(0xc2080b79e0){HostPath:<nil> EmptyDir:<nil> GCEPersistentDisk:<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:<nil> 
GitRepo:<nil> Secret:<nil> NFS:<nil> ISCSI:<nil> Glusterfs:<nil> PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource:<nil> RBD:<nil>}': 
exactly 1 volume type is required spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: not found 'string']
```

**What is the correct way to specify a volume for container?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `hostDir` with `hostPath` as mentioned in [v1beta3-conversion-tips-from-v1beta12](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/api.md#v1beta3-conversion-tips-from-v1beta12).

Try replacing

```
volumes:
    - name: string
      source:
        # Either emptyDir for an empty directory
        # emptyDir: {}
        # Or hostDir for a pre-existing directory on the host
        hostDir:
          path: /home
```

with

```
volumes:
    - name: string
      hostPath:
        path: /home
```

at the bottom of your configuration.

Comment: It seems that it didn't help.

Comment: The `source:` line also has to go - `hostPath` is no longer nested under `source`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do it:

`version: v1
kind: Pod
spec:
  containers:
    - name: simple-echo
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: ['nc', '-p', '8080', '-l', '-l', '-e', 'echo', 'hello world!']
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          hostPort: 8080
          protocol: TCP
      volumeMounts:
        - name: string
          mountPath: /home
          readOnly: false
  restartPolicy: Always
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
    - /path/dir/from/host:/name/of/dir/in/container`

Comment: It doesn't work: `couldn't parse as single (json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type api.Volume) or multiple pods (json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type api.Volume)`